# Find partial derivative at point $(0,0)$ of $(xy)/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

It's a bit wierd question but I have to ask it.

$$ \text{Let }\space f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2},  & \text{if $(x, y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

The following question is:

> Do partial derivatives of $f(x, y)$ exist at $(0, 0)$? If so, find them. if not, prove.

As I know it should be simple,

Just derive $\dfrac{df}{\partial x} 0 = 0, \dfrac{df}{\partial y} 0 = 0$.

But I must admit it seems wierd. where have I wrong?

How should I solve such questions? thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the definition of partial derivative?

Comment: @GitGud It's a ordinary derivative where the not respected variable treated as constant.. no?

Comment: That's analysts jargon, give me mathematical symbols.

Comment: You cannot just "derive". Instead, use the definition of partial derivative at $0$, and compute explicitly $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}h$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}k$.

Comment: So the function has partial derivatives even though it’s not differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Note that, the partial derivatives exists at the origin while the function fails to be continuous there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really do need to know the definition in order to figure this problem out. That is, the limit definition:
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{h \cdot 0}{h^2+0} - 0}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{0}{h} = 0
$$
and so the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is zero. Similarly,
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = \lim_{k\to 0} \dfrac{f(0,k) - f(0,0)}{k} = 0
$$
and so the partial with respect to $y$ is also zero. There are functions that seemingly have partial derivatives at a point at a first glance, but once you plug them into the limit definition, you see it doesn't. For example, try changing the numerator of your function from $x \cdot y$ to $x + y$: the limits in the definition for the partials at zero are not even finite for this one!